# JavaScript variable value to fluctuate between two values

Tags: javascript, variables, integer

I'm trying to get a JS variable to fluctuate between two values over time.

For example, let's say we start with `var counter = 0`, and every second this variable increases by one.

How would I make it so that at `counter == 3` the value decreases by one until `counter == -3`, at which point it increases again until 3 and then back down again, and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so :

```
var counter = 0;
var inc = +1;
setInterval(function(){
    if(counter == 3) inc = -1;
    if(counter == -3) inc = +1;
    counter+= inc;
}, 1000);
```

See this sample : http://jsfiddle.net/VQFLd/3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var increment = 1;
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    counter += increment;
    console.log(counter);
    if (counter === 3) {
        increment = -1;
    } else if (counter === -3) {
        increment = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var currentNumber = 0;
var increase = true;

setInterval(function (){changeValues(-3,3);},1000);

function changeValues(minimum,maximum){
    if(increase){
        if(currentNumber == (maximum-1))
        increase = false;
        currentNumber++;
    }else{
        if(currentNumber == (minimum+1))
        increase = true;
        currentNumber--;
    }
}
```